# Escaping characters in Objective C on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, escaping

I'm trying to pass the following string:

```
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFunc(\"%@\");", myParameter];
```

from Objective C to JavaScript using the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, where myParameter is a string value. How can I ensure that the myParameter string doesn't contain any JS-unsafe characters without being properly escaped?

E.g. the following string would mess things up:

```
parameter");alert('scam');
```

The myParameter string will be the name of a contact from the address book, making it perfectly possible to have the above string entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace every `"` with `\"`:

```
NSString* filteredParam = [myParameter stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];
NSString* filteredParam = [filteredParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
```

Comment: KennyTM, what the code you provided does is replace every `"\""` with `"\\\""`, and not replace every `"` with `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usage requirements, you could use a 'template' approach:

```
#define JSTemplateCodeKey @"##JS_CODE_HERE##"

// define template (or read it from file, ect...)
NSString *jsTemplate = @"myFunc(\"" JSTemplateCodeKey "\");";

// replace the placeholder in your template with your param
NSString *jsString = [jsTemplate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:JSTemplateCodeKey withString:myParameter];
```